# Rewrite Nginx/Apache Rewrite Rule to IIS

Tags: apache, nginx, iis

I have a rewrite rule for Apache and a Nginx version. Both should be same.

URL Rewrite rules:

**Apache**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Nginx**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Now I have to host my site on a IIS server. How do I transfer this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below IIS url rewrite rule:

Notice: If you want to use url rewrite in the IIS, you should install the url rewrite extension in below url : https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```